# manage json datetime response in asp.net forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

First of all, sorry for my confusing English, I'll try to explain me as best I can.
I am programming a website that allows to verify identity certifications by a verifying code, so that the user can buy one of these documents online, and the code allows any person or government entity to verify the veracity of the document.
for this purpose, i programmed a wcf service that works perfectly, and an asp .net site that receives the code, sends it to the service and it returns the data, if it exists. if not exist, the website says it, cause has error handling and null data control
my problem is with the handling of the issuance date, because in the database (managed in mysql), the date is well saved, but when it is received on the website, it returns the following

01/01/0001 00:00:00 000

I have tried, converting the column in the database from datetime format to string, doing the conversion in the wcf service, even converting the date data in the web form, or defining this property in the classes in datetime or string. for the moment, this is my code and works, but i can't show the date in right form.

this is the JSON response. maybe here is the problem, but can't see it

```
{"ID":39000,"DNI":123456789,"Code":"D025000","Name":"JOSE","Date":"\/Date(1608076800000+0000)\/"}
```

this is the default.aspx.cs form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

//  
public class Root
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int dni { get; set; }
    public string certcode { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime issuedate { get; set; }
}

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void cmd_check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label2.Visible = true;
            Label3.Visible = true;
            Label4.Visible = true;
            Label5.Visible = true;
            Label6.Visible = true;
            Label7.Visible = true;
            Label8.Visible = true;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://mywebsite.net/Service.svc/CheckCert/"+txt_code.Text+"");
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
                if (myDeserializedClass.certcode==null){
                    Label1.Visible = true;
                    Label1.Text = "document not found";
                    Label2.Visible = false;
                    Label3.Visible = false;
                    Label4.Visible = false;
                    Label5.Visible = false;
                    Label6.Visible = false;
                    Label7.Visible = false;
                    Label8.Visible = false;
                    Label9.Visible = false;
                    Label10.Visible = false;


                }
                else { 
                Label1.Visible = true;
                    Label1.Text = "name";
                    Label2.Visible = true;
                Label3.Visible = true;
                Label4.Visible = true;
                Label5.Visible = true;
                Label6.Visible = true;
                Label7.Visible = true;
                Label8.Visible = true;
                    Label9.Visible = true;
                Label10.Visible = true;
                Label2.Text = myDeserializedClass.name;
                Label4.Text = myDeserializedClass.dni.ToString();
                Label6.Text = myDeserializedClass.id.ToString();
                Label8.Text = myDeserializedClass.certcode;
                    Label10.Text = myDeserializedClass.issuedate.ToString();
                        ;
                }

            }


        }

        catch {
            Label1.Visible = true;
            Label1.Text = "document not found";
            Label2.Visible = false;
            Label3.Visible = false;
            Label4.Visible = false;
            Label5.Visible = false;
            Label6.Visible = false;
            Label7.Visible = false;
            Label8.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

this is the real result when i query the data in the website, as a real customer. the website is in spanish cause the users are in Costa Rica

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/may1q.png)

can you help me? thanks a lot

Comment: what format do you want to receive the date?

Comment: @ademg in DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS if possible

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to adding the following code

```
JsonSerializerSettings microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
};
 Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json,microsoftDateFormatSettings);
```

after that check what is the value of your issuedate

I made a working example you can check it out on the following link
https://dotnetfiddle.net/EC8cwH

Comment: hi @ademg your example works, but not in my scenario. i'll show you a functional code with the real svc